# Custom pdf with parameters and support with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I want to build a custom pdf using the rv_continuous class; such a pdf should depend on a couple of parameters, `l1, l2, l3` in the example below. This is my attempt:

```
k=1
class estimated_pdf(scipy.stats.rv_continuous):


    def _get_support(self, l1, l2, l3):
         self.a=0
         self.b=np.inf
    

    def _pdf(self, x, l1, l2, l3):
        return np.exp(-l1*x/k-l2*x**2/k-l3*x**3/k)


    def Z(self, l1, l2, l3):
        return quad(self._pdf, 0, np.inf, args=(l1, l2, l3))

    # edited
    def my_freeze(self, l1, l2, l3):
        self.l1 = l1
        self.l2 = l2
        self.l3 = l3


p = estimated_pdf()
# p.__call__(l1=1, l2=2, l3=3)
p.my_freeze(l1=1, l2=2, l3=3)
```

I get the following problems:

1. " _get_support() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given "; the support should not depend on the parameters, so I'm not sure how to handle this
2. if I comment out the _get_support part I get instead: " _parse_args() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'l1', 'l2', and 'l3' "

I have no clue what's happening, 1. is not happy because I gave it the `l1, l2, l3` parameters while it looks like 2. is not happy becasue I didn't give it.

Edit: I realised that using `__call__` or `freeze` would change my object to be again a rv_continuous object instead of a estimated_pdf object, so I added my own `my_freeze` function to solve that issue.
I also added the `l1, l2, l3` parameters to the `_get_support`. Right now no errors are raised, but by checking the support, I get that it's the full real line, i.e. the dafault value, so `_get_support` still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

`_get_support` is expected to receive the same shape arguments as the PDF, here `l1 l2, l3`.

IIUC, if the support is the real semi axis, and does not depend on l1, l2, l3, you do not need to explicitly define `get_support`. Just omit it.

PS : Your snippet has a bunch of other issues. `k` is undefined in the PDF; Z method does not return anything.

EDIT: Like so:

```
In [8]: from numpy import exp

In [9]: class my_distr_gen(rv_continuous):
   ...:     def _get_support(self, l1, l2, l3):
   ...:         return 0, float('inf')
   ...:     def _pdf(self, x, l1, l2, l3):
   ...:         return exp(-l1*x - l2*x**2 - l3*x**3)  # NB: normalize!
   ...: 

In [10]: my_distr = my_distr_gen()

In [11]: my_distr.pdf(1, l1=1, l2=2, l3=3)
Out[11]: 0.0024787521766663585

In [12]: my_distr.pdf(-1, l1=1, l2=2, l3=3)
Out[12]: 0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but `_get_support` still doesn't work. I need to define the support because the default is the full real line, not the semi axis. Please read the edit.

Comment: Your `_get_support` needs to return `self.a` and `self.b`. Or better `return 0, np.inf`.