# SciPy - Custom probability density function and generating samples from it

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following probability density function:
`f(x) = 0.5*exp(-0.5*(x - a))` where `a` is a parameter. For each value of `a` we have one distinct pdf. Following this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71894504/custom-pdf-with-parameters-and-support-with-scipy), my code is as below:

```py
class exp_pdf(rv_continuous):
    def _get_support(self, param):
        return 0, float('inf')
    def _pdf(self, x, param):
        return beta*np.exp(-beta*(x - param))
```

Then I plot the PDF for an arbitrary value of `param`, for example, `param = 1`. The plot is correct:

```py
param_temp = 1
exp_dist = exp_pdf(a = param_temp, name='Custom Exponential Function')
points = np.linspace(1, 10, 100)
plt.plot(points, exp_dist.pdf(points, param = param_temp), 'r-', lw=2)
```

[image]

However, when I try to generate samples from this pdf, the samples are not matched:

```
samples = exp_dist.rvs(size = 100, param = param_temp)
plt.hist(samples, bins = 30, density = True, alpha = 0.7)
```

[image]

If I don't use `_get_support` and hardcode the value of `param`, the histogram and the density function match well:

```py
class exp_pdf(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return beta*np.exp(-beta*(x - 1))

exp_dist = exp_pdf(a = 1, name = 'Custom Exponential Function')
points = np.linspace(1, 10, 100)
plt.plot(points, exp_dist.pdf(points), 'r-', lw = 2)

samples = exp_dist.rvs(size = 100)
plt.hist(samples, bins = 30, density = True, alpha = 0.7)
```

[image]

May I ask for your suggestions on this matter? How do I get `_get_support` to work correctly for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distribution is not defined for `x < param`. Try this definition:

```py
class exp_pdf(rv_continuous):
    def _get_support(self, param):
        return param, float('inf')
    def _pdf(self, x, param):
        return beta*np.exp(-beta*(x - param))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't notice the feasible region first.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exponential distribution, scipy.stats.expon, with your `param` being , in scipy.stats parlance, `loc`:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html

So just use `expon.rvs(scale=0.5, loc=param)`

Comment: It's just an example, I will encounter some other custom pdf.

Comment: My point is first make sure to check that the distribution you are implementing does not have extra shape parameters which are in fact loc and/or scale. Those may well confuse the infrastructure.